# Ajax php function call requires followup statement?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, return

I have been working on a part of code where a piece of PHP has to be executed on a submit event. For some reason however, it requires that an alert (or maybe some other type of statement) is required. If this alert is missing however, it appears that the whole ajax request is not executed at all. I have tried to replace the alert with a return but that does not help anything. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").submit(function() {
        var derp = "Bla";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "signup.php",
            data: { "email" : derp }
        }).done(function(data ) {
            alert( data );
        });
        alert("This is a bug???"); // removing this line will cause problems
    });
});
```

Comment: The form is probably submitting and reloading the page, you have to preventDefault.

Comment: are you using button type submit?

Comment: The form im using is: 

<form id="sub" action="">
            <input type="text" name="email">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
How should i use preventDefault? That has to be on an event, which I have not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").submit(function(event) {
        var derp = "Bla";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "signup.php",
            data: { "email" : derp }
        }).done(function(data ) {
            alert( data );
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```